# TypeScript type inference issue when function returns function

Tags: typescript, type-inference, ramda.js

I have a following example functions (compose is from Ramda):

```
    declare function compose<V0, T1, T2>(fn1: (x: T1) => T2, fn0: (x0: V0) => T1): (x0: V0) => T2;

    interface User {
      id: number
    }

    function fn1(input: any): User {
      return {id: 1};
    }

    function fn2<I, O>(fn: (i: I) => O): (i: I) => O {
       return (data) => {
         try {
           return fn(data);
         } catch (e) {
           return undefined
         }
      };
    }
```

When I tried to use it like this:

```
compose(fn2(user => user.id), fn1);
```

TypeScript throws a following error:

`TS2339:Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Does anyone know, what should I do to help TypeScript to infer a proper type for `user`?

Of course, following code will work:

```
compose<any, User, number>(fn2(user => user.id), fn1);
```

Comment: UPDATE: Looks like TypeScript team is aware of this behaviour, so at least, it is not a bug. See [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15680#issuecomment-307571917).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that parametric types are resolved left to right and because you are writing an any to any function first you have that error. Look at this code which is similar but the functions are reversed:

```
declare function compose<V0, T1, T2>(fn0: (x0: V0) => T1, fn1: (x: T1) => T2,): (x0: V0) => T2;

interface User {
  id: number
}

function fn1(input: number): User {
  return {id: 1};
}

function fn2<I, O>(fn: (i: I) => O): (i: I) => O {
   return (data) => {
     try {
       return fn(data);
     } catch (e) {
       return undefined
     }
  };
}

compose(fn1, fn2(user => user.id));
```

It works as you would expect. but the compose definition must be changed.

## Edit

Similar to Titian Cernicova's answer, you can define at least the first parametric element that goes into your compose chain like this:

```
declare function compose<T1 = any, T2 = any, V0 = any>(fn1: (x: T1) => T2, fn0: (x0: V0) => T1): (x0: V0) => T2;

interface User {
  id: number
}

function fn1(input: number): User {
  return {id: 1};
}

function fn2<I, O>(fn: (i: I) => O): (i: I) => O {
   return (data) => {
     try {
       return fn(data);
     } catch (e) {
       return undefined
     }
  };
}

compose<User>(fn2(user => user.id), fn1);
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure if it is a bug or just a limitation of TypeScript. According to your idea, I decided to use [pipe](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe), which allows me to use functions in a reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify all the types but you need to specify the `user` parameter type for this to work.

```
compose(fn2((user: User) => user.id), fn1);
```

If you were to not use `fn2` type inference would work, but deciding that `fn2`'s argument has to be of type `(user:User)=> number` based on the required value to be returned by fn2 is a bit too much for the Typescript compiler.

This works:

```
compose((user) => user.id, fn1);
```